# How do I use IF/OR to fill in data from a table in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've been experimenting with IF and OR functions for a data set. I've created a smaller version to communicate my point.

[Photo of Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu7Nb.png)

I want to write a formula where if data in Column-B matched any of the data in Column-E, the date in Column-F would automatically be typed into Column-C i.e. 11/11/2023 would be next to 'a', because it's next to 'a' in the right hand side data set. Similary, the date 11/12/2023 next to 'f' in the right hand data set, would show up next to 'f' in Column-C.

The data on the right would not have any duplicates i.e. there is only ever one date for each letter.

Please help me with this. I'm struggling to find a functioning formula.

Comment: To clarify column C would only ever have a date in a row if the adjacent cell in column B had a match with a row in column E?

Comment: Yes, the cell in Column C would be blank when Column B doesn't have a match in Column E

Comment: Is there anything specific you need IF/OR for? This sounds easy enough to do with an Xlookup.

Comment: Nothing specific! I'm just not too familiar with other things so I thought it was necessary, but if it's not, i'm really open to any solutions that will work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your question and picture, [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) is very easy to use for looking at things.
If we assume that this is starting at row 1, then putting the following in `C2` and drag it down:

```
=XLOOKUP(B2,E$2:E$7,F$2:F$7,"")
```

Syntax:
**=XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array, [if_not_found], [match_mode], [search_mode])**

Answer (score 0):

##### Formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Date2,MATCH(A2,Data2,0),2),"")
```

| Data1 | Date1 | Data2 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1/11/2023 | a | 1/11/2023 |
| b |  | s | 11/23/2023 |
| c |  | k | 10/2/2022 |
| d | 10/1/2022 | d | 10/1/2022 |
| e |  | f | 12/11/2023 |
| f | 12/11/2023 | z | 7/7/2022 |